# Remote Access VPN clients and Endpoint services fail after January 1st, 2021… but the solution was being an avid reader of their forum

Tags: windows, vpn, checkpoint-endpoint

I am having trouble with CheckPoint Endpoint Security VPN. I have this VPN installed for work reasons. I had to connect to the VPN today, and i got this error:

[image]

First i tried a couple of solutions i found online but nothing worked. I then tried to repair the software via control panel, but it did not work. Then i made my last decision to uninstall it, in order to reinstall it later... but uninstall fails, and uninstall process remains hanged indefinitely.

Went back to the web, and after 1 hour of further investigation i've found this article on their website(website that by the way requires an account to read forum solutions(LOL)):
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk171213

This page states candidly that the software will stop working on 2021-01-01, and upgrades will fail as well as attempts to uninstall. The only solution is to install a patch provided by the page, but...

[image]

So, i guess that, since i was not able to locate their article, now i cannot:

1. unistall the program;
2. update the program;
3. use the patch.

So, what's next? I cannot believe i am the only one going through this.

Comment: Presumably, this should have been organised by your IT department. Have you asked them?

Comment: First off, thanks for replying. What if i am a freelancer that has many clients, each one imposing me a different VPN client to reach their servers. I could go ask the client about this issue, and ask them if they know about it... but i really would not bother them unless it's strictly inevitable